# cmake find_path where path includes version numbers

Tags: cmake, qwt

I'm trying to write a FindQwt.cmake module. I've googled the existing modules and none of them work for my installation.

My module's find path call currently looks like this:

```
find_path ( QWT_INCLUDE_DIR
      NAMES qwt_global.h
      HINTS ${QT_INCLUDE_DIR}
      PATHS
      /opt
      /usr/include
      /usr/local
      /usr/local/include
      "$ENV{LIB_DIR}/include"
      "$ENV{INCLUDE}"
      PATH_SUFFIXES qwt
    )
```

The actual `qwt_global.h` file resides at the path: /opt/qwt-6.1.2/src/qwt_global.h

I can get this to work if I add the path suffix `qwt-6.1.2/src`, but it seems to me like it's going to defeat the purpose of having a find module if I need to hard code every version into it (Assume I'm checking later in the module that the versions are compatible and don't care which version is used within the compatible set).

I've tried `qwt*` and `qwt*/src` in the PATH_SUFFIXES, but to no avail.

It seems like this would be a common problem. Does anyone know how to fix this `find_path` call to be robust to having version numbers in the path?

**EDIT:** I'm using cmake 3.0.2

Comment: No idea about cmake, but the proper place for finding the version number would be qwtconfig.pri - not qwtglobal.h. At least then you are in a more general situation of cmake vs. qmake.
Also a path of /opt/qwt-6.1.2/src indicates that you skipped the "make install" step, what is not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Unfortunately my distro is installed on a read only file system and /opt is one of the few places I have access to.

Comment: What is no argument for skipping the "make install" step. F.e edit qwtconfig.pri and set the install path to something in /opt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `FILE(GLOB ...)` for this.

```
file(GLOB QWT_SEARCH_PATHS "/opt/qwt-*" "/usr/include/qwt-*")
find_path(QWT_INCLUDE_DIR 
    NAMES qwt_global.h
    PATHS ${QWT_SEARCH_PATHS})
```

For a cleaner implementation, build a list of directories, then iterate the list to append the "qwt-*" glob.